# What is the use of JwtIssuerOptions in appsetting?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, jwt

```
"JwtIssuerOptions": {
    "Issuer": "webApi",
    "Audience": "http://localhost:4200/"
}
```

What does it do exactly? Where is the WebApi from?

Comment: `webApi` It`s just a string that represent issuer in your context. 
You can read more about options here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s probably being used to validate id token claims that are used in authentication. Issuer is the identity provider meaning the api that issues the token. Audience is the api for which this token is for, it will be this api In question.